# How to remove examples.o files from the framework in IOS?

Tags: ios, xcode7, cocoapods

I have use AFNetworking library using cocoapods. my project was running fine but when i drag third party framework in my existing project it give me error of duplication symbols in armv7.
I have listed out .o files in the framework using terminal

```
$ lipo frameworkName -info 
$ lipo frameworkName -thin armv7 -output frameworkName.armv7
$ ar -t frameworkName.armv7
```

Its displaying some .o files which are also present in the AFnetworking library like AFURLSessionManager.o
When I try to remove those file using command

```
$ ar -d -sv frameworkName.armv7 AFURLSessionManager.o
```

its not removing those files.
For sake I have removed -ObjC flag from the Other Linker Flags but doing so my some other cocoapods libraries are not working.
Please assist me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your third party library contains AFURLSessionManager class..?

Comment: it is containing AFURLSessionManager.o file in armv7 architecture

Comment: Why can't you fix the build instead of the final executable?

Comment: its giving me 154 duplicate symbols error on armv7

Answer (score 0):

AFURLSessionManager.o appears when AFURLSessionManager.m is not added to target. Try to check Target Membership for AFURLSessionManager.m in File inspector. It should fix the issue.

Comment: Milan Before dragging the Framework my application is working fine.... but just after dragging it give me duplicate symbol errors

Comment: Yes there are only 2 files in header of the framework only